# Providing two widgets for a single form field in Django forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms

```
import django.contrib.auth.forms as auth_forms
import models
from django import forms
from notification import models as notification

class UserCreationForm(auth_forms.UserCreationForm):
    def clean_username(self):
         # Since User.username is unique, this check is redundant,
         # but it sets a nicer error message than the ORM. See #13147.
         username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
         try:
             self._meta.model._default_manager.get(username=username)
         except models.User.DoesNotExist:
             return username
         raise forms.ValidationError(
              self.error_messages['duplicate_username'],
              code='duplicate_username',
         )

     class Meta:
        model = models.User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'role')


class TeacherCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(
        label='Password',
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
        required=False
    )
```

Instead of the above TeacherCreationForm i need something like below:

```
class TeacherCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(
        label='Password',
        widget=(forms.PasswordInput, forms.HiddenInput),
        required=False
    )
```

Because i want to hide the password field, as it will automatically generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...
class TeacherCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        exclude = ("password1")